# Dispatch event from lwc to another lwc that is not in the same DOM tree

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I have a lwc that dispatches an event to be received by another lwc that's not in the same DOM tree.

This is my child lwc block of code:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newfilesuccess'));
```

And this is my listener lwc (not parent):

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.addEventListener('newfilesuccess', this.handleFileSuccess);
}
handleFileSuccess = () => {
  console.log('success!');
}
```

But I can't manage to handle communication between both lwcs. How can I achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: Another good Trailhead in this is [Communicate Between Unrelated Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-between-unrelated-components). I've seen this over-used in an app so recommend you use it sparingly e.g. your example case looks reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

For anything other than direct parent-to-child or child-to-parent communication, you need to use a [Publish-Subscribe Pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-for-aura-developers/communicate-with-events) (this links to an Aura Trailhead). Fortunately, there's already a built-in library for this, called the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation). Basically, you first design a [channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_intro) that your two components can `subscribe` to in `connectedCallback`, and `unsubscribe` from in `disconnectedCallback` (to free memory resources). Any component subscribed to the channel will get any notifications published through the `publish` function. This is interoperable between both Aura and LWC components anywhere in the same DOM, even if they are not directly related in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed!

Comment: @molinet You're welcome!

Comment: Be aware that (as far as I can find) [LMS support is still beta in digital experiences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_considerations.htm) (as it has been since Spring '21). This is a concern if you need to use it in a production implementation.

Comment: It was GA'd in [Winter '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_lms_ga.htm&type=5&release=234) for Aura/LWC sites. May have to flag that document to see if it needs updating